# Django model views | How to Update objects from id_parameter to last, and increment 1 to value?

Tags: python, django, filter, view

`Django` model views | How to Update objects from id_parameter to last, and increment 1 to value ?

```
def view_update():
    car.objects.filter(from id to last).update(field=+1) # or delete
```

how i can do , "from id to last"?

thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `id__gte=..` argument. And use [`F()` query expression](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/db/queries/#query-expressions) to update:

```
from django.db.models import F

Car.objects.filter(id__gte=id_parameter).update(F('field') + 1)
```

Comment: Car.objects.filter(compaso__gte=id_compaso).update(my_field=F('field')-1), work for me!, thank you, __gte very important, and F() function util, im only need to add "name_of_field and =".

Comment: One dubt, Car.objects.filter(compaso__gte=id_compaso).update(my_field=F('field')-1), this work good!, but need to add minus a variable "-1" to "-variable" but dont work, thanks.

Comment: @user3184225, Is the variable an int object? Check the type of the object that the variable is referencing.

Comment: Yes, it is a int, and i`m understand what you say, when im looking for, i`m try again , and... work!, with "variable = object.field and then minus variable", thanks.